# What is the numbering convention in .conf files(inside a conf.d)?

Tags: xorg, configuration, conventions

Inside the `xorg.conf.d/` for example, we have three files:

```
00-keyboard.conf  10-monitor.conf  30-touchpad.conf
```

I know that the 2-digit number determine the precedence that each file is read so `00-keyboard.conf` is read before `10-monitor.conf`.

But I noticed that documentation on different sites all seems to use the same convention, e.g., using `10-monitor.conf` for monitor configurations.

So, what I want to know is if there are numbers mapped to certain devices or if is just a convention that everyone stick with and I can use whatever 2-digit number that I want (according to precedences, of course). And if they are mapped, where can I find them?

I have searched about it but everything I found just mention what I have just said and doesn't mention if I can use other numbers or not. Even the `xorg.conf[5]` man page does not mention anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no mapping to devices or anything like that. The numbering is only used to enforce an order, and you don’t even have to name your configuration files with a number at the start — it’s just easier to reason about order with numbers.

So you can use any scheme you want.